# jquery second click works

Tags: jquery, function, click

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

var $cityToggler=$("#choose-city");


function showSelector(){
    var $citySelector=$("#city-selector");

    if ($citySelector.hasClass("opened")){
        $citySelector.slideDown().removeClass("opened");
        $cityToggler.addClass("pressed");
    } else {
        $citySelector.slideUp("fast").addClass("opened");
        $cityToggler.removeClass("pressed");

    }
}
$("#choose-city, #close-selector").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showSelector();
});

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fwyukjom/

in my opinion, "city selector" should be opened with a first click on the link "Select City". 
But it only opens from the second click and then works fine. (Opened-closed)

where i did mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opened class did not exist on first click , and created when click again.

You can use the easier way like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("span:contains(Select city)").on("click",function(){

        $(".city-selector").slideToggle(2000);

    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .city-selector{
  display:none;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
 <div id="city-selector" class="city-selector hide">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <a href="#" id="close-selector">
                 <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>
             </a>
             <p>your city</p>
             <p class="h1">Moscow</p>
         </div>
                    
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row rel">
        <div class="col-md-offset-8">
            <a href="#" id="choose-city" class="current-city"> 
                <span>Select city</span>
                <i class="fa"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("span:contains(Select city)").on("click",function(){

            $(".city-selector").slideToggle(2000);

        })
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why should he try this? Explain what was wrong with his code and how you fixed it, don't just post code.

Comment: @Barmar , opened class did not exist on first click , and created when click again.

Comment: Put the explanation in the answer, not a comment.

Comment: do it, tanks Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic was just a little confused. Try this:

```
function showSelector(){
    var $citySelector=$("#city-selector");
        $citySelector.toggleClass('opened');

    if ($citySelector.hasClass("opened")){
        $citySelector.slideDown();
        $cityToggler.addClass("pressed");
    } else {
        $citySelector.slideUp("fast");
        $cityToggler.removeClass("pressed");

    }
}
```

Basically, the `opened` class did not exist on first click, so you need to add/remove **before** the logic blocks.